# PhpUnit Assert if string contains on numeric characters

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Just wondering on how to test if a string contains on numeric characters.

I tried

```
$testdata = [           
   'ver'  => '087'
];

$this->assertRegExp('/0-9/',$testdata['ver']);
```

but the above fails.

Comment: All numeric or just one numeric character?  `contains on` isn't clear.

Comment: @Devon all numeric

Comment: I would imagine `$this->assertRegExp('/^\d+$/',$testdata['ver']);` would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All numbers would have to be:

```
^[0-9]+$
```

Ranges have to be enclosed in brackets.  However, just `[0-9]` is just going to match anything with one number.

You can also use `\d` to represent any digit.

```
^\d+$
```

If you want to take advantage of PHP's is_numeric check, you could also perform the assertion this way:

```
$this->assertTrue(is_numeric($testdata['ver']));
```